# gridbag layout GUI

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I am having problems with the gridbag layout, I am trying to get the images to be on one line horizontally, however when I add images to the left of the original one, it will go down vertically instead of going horizontally to the left.

I have tried to specify the gridY to be the same, however this did not work, also I have tried the GridBayConstarints.Horizontal however that was irrelevant.

So far I have

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class main {


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GUI g = new GUI();

    int turnCounter = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {

        String image = "src/resources/bone"+0+i+".png";
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();


        //ADDS IMAGE TO THE LEFT 
        if(turnCounter%2 == 0)
        {
            c.gridy = c.gridy;
            c.gridx = c.gridx-1;
            ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(image);
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel((ImageIcon) icon1);
            g.add(label1,c);
            g.revalidate();

            turnCounter++;
        }

        //ADD IMAGES TO THE RIGHT
        else if(turnCounter%2 == 1)
        {

            c.gridy = c.gridy;
            c.gridx = c.gridx+1;
            ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(image);
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel((ImageIcon) icon1);
            g.add(label1,c);
            g.revalidate();
            turnCounter++;
        }
    }



}
```

}

What the image looks like at the moment.
The [2|0] and [3|0] should be to the left of [0|0] in that order so it will look like this

[4|0][2|0][0|0][1|0][3|0][5|0] all in one line.

[image: Image of what it looks like at the moment]

Answer (score 0):

The code you used for putting things to the right is correct, but as the **default value of gridx is 0**, what you are doing when you try to add a **component to the left is giving a value to gridx of -1**, an **incorrect value** for gridx, seems like the problem is there.

The solution I can give right now, is making an array with a lenght of how many images you want to display, in this case it would be a:

```
int yourLenght = 5; //Sounds dirty lol
JLabel[] yourArray;
yourArray = new JLabel[myLenght]
```

After this, only select the place of the array where you want to place it, I would recommend it in the middle.

**Why does this work?**

Now your images can only be on the 5th  or 1st column (gridx = 0), but not on -1, altough we haven't finished yet, if you leave it like this, and you add or quit one to "yourLenght" your images could only be placed on the 2nd column or the 4th one, cause you can only add or quit one to 3. To avoid these what we are going to do is declare another int.

```
int magicInt = 1;
```

And then after each component is added we will add 1 to the "magicInt" value.

```
//You already added the object rather on the left or on the right
magicInt++;
```

And that way each time you add an object you can advance one place to the left or to the right more.

**Notes:**

1-Anchors won't work if you don't give a value to weighty. You can read more about these variables [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

2-I discourage using

```
c.gridy = c.gridy;
```

If you are only going to use that loop for adding things on one row, better use:

```
c.gridy = 0;
```

That way your code is easier to read.

3- Solution listed above only works if objects are added consitently with the following pattern : left, right, left, right... or right, left, right, left...
(It was a quick solution, but you will find your solution just think...)

Hope, this helped you, if you have any doubts don't mind commenting that way I can help :)